# Am i a hypocrite?

Tags: doubts, waswasa

Assalamualaikum,

The other day i search at google what does allah name means. I feel really terrible after searching it, i felt like i’ve done shirk. Its making my heart and mind unease, and i’m afraid of losing my faith. I really need counseling.

Sometimes, when i think about allah i have doubts about allah all of a sudden for no reasons, is it waswas or i’m being a hypocrite. I’m feeling depressed these couple of month just thinking about that i’m being a hypocrite and have done shirk.

I’m sorry about my bad english. Hope you guys can understand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I a kafir because of my doubts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36105/am-i-a-kafir-because-of-my-doubts)

Comment: Imam al-Ghazaly said I doubt so I exist, as long as we question things we are able to learn, as we will try to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

So you feel guilty because you tried to learn something and you prefer to remain ignorant instead?

It is not frowned upon to ask questions with the intention of increasing your knowledge otherwise how will you know what is permissible and what is not, you will never know every thing and it is inevitable that you will have to ask questions at some point:

> And We sent not before you except men to whom We revealed [Our
>   message]. **So ask the people of the message if you do not know**. (Quran 16:43 and 21:7)

Your question can and should be split into two, the second part has probably been addressed on this site many times already.